# Managing authors of Joomla articles

Tags: articles, com-content, joomla-3.9, article-manager

We have a Joomla site with a few people managing it, adding articles written by numerous other authors. I would like to set the author name for each article and show it in the front end in the article info box (and possibly work with it in other ways like listing all articles by the same author).

Could you please explain to me a little bit about the treatment of article authors in Joomla? In the administration of articles in the tab **Publishing** there are fields *Created By*, *Created by Alias* and *Author*. *Created By* is apparently the username of the Joomla user who actually created the Article, while *Created by Alias* and *Author* can be freely edited. What I find baffling is that a column labelled **Author** in the back end list of articles shows values from the fields *Created By* and *Created by Alias* rather than the field *Author*. Is it a mistake or is there any reason why it is labelled this way? Same in the front end: When I set the **Show Author** option to 'Show', then what appears in the info box of the article is either the *Created By* or *Created by Alias* value instead of the *Author* value. From what I found out, the only thing the *Author* field does is that it adds a `<meta name="author">` tag. But there is no indication in the administration that this field only applies to metadata, so I find it quite misleading. Or have I missed something?

Anyway, how can I achieve what I asked in the beginning? I find it useful (though not necessary) to keep a distinction between who created the article in the system (the editor working with Joomla) vs. who is the author of the text being published. Or do I have to create fake Joomla users for all the authors of the texts and assign the articles to them? And what if there is a text with multiple authors? What is the best practice to do these things? Thanks in advance for an explanation.

Comment: 1. All the fields on the right side of the publishing tabs are metatags.  2. Why is the Author Alias field not sufficient for what you wish to achieve? 3. For more advanced data you would use custom fields. I can convert this comment to a question if is turns out to be sufficient - but I think it may not be.

Comment: I see, it is quite logical that all the fields on the right side are metatags, but it is not clear in the but it is not clear in the admin. And I still think the labels are misleading, for the reasons I wrote above.
Anyway, Author Alias will be surely the easiest way to achieve the basic function of just writing the Author name.But if I wanted the added functionality of linking to the list of articles by the same author, can that be achieved with custom fields (I haven't worked with them yet) or is there a good extension for that?

Comment: You can generate a list of articles filtered to an author or author alias using an Articles - Category Module.  I've only seen filtering by custom fields as part of a custom development - but if you end up using the author alias then the module is good to go.